# jQuery - Fader with Multiple Instances

Tags: jquery

I'm building a jQuery driven fader, and I would like to have multiple instances on a page.

> **Goal**: I'm trying to build this from scratch without the assistance of a plugin.
>
> > **What I've Tried**:
> >     1. Used this keyword/selector to create the variables needed, but am not getting what I need.
> >     2. I had also setup a function with arguements, to find out the hard way jQuery won't seem to pass variables in this manner. Most lessons are best learned the hard way anyways.
>
> **Problem**: I've been thru a handful of iterations locally with different results. I'm currently getting a too much recursion error, although it does work locally in some form.
>
> **Thoughts**: My next step would have been object notation, but was fearful of spinning my wheels with another wrong solution.
>
> Thanks everyone

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UQmc3/

Code Samples to Follow
**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <div class="w-fader">
        <ul class="w-slides">
            <li class="current"><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-1.png" /></li>
            <li class="next"><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-3.png" /></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="w-fader">
        <ul class="w-slides">
            <li class="current"><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-1.png" /></li>
            <li class="next"><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-3.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-1.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://littleredplanedesign.com/labs/rotator/rotator-images/fader-img-3.png" /></li>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery/js**:

```
var speed = 2000;
var name = 'fader';
var num = 1;

function setupUnique(){
$('.w-slides').each(function(){
    var panelId = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(panelId);
    var nextItem = $(this).find('li.next');
    //alert(nextItem);
    var currentItem = $(this).find('li.current');
    var wrapHelperItem = $(this).find('.w-slides li.current+li');   
    var firstSwapItem = $(this).find('li:first');   
    var lastSwapItem = $(this).find('li:last'); 

    fadePanels();
    function fadePanels(){
    $('#'+panelId).each(function(){
        switcher();
        function switcher(){
        $(nextItem).animate({opacity:1}, speed, 'linear', function()
            {
                $(nextItem).removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
                $(nextItem).addClass('next');
                $(this).removeClass('next');
                $(nextItem).css('opacity',0);
            });
        checker();
        }       

        //checker();

        function checker(){
        if($(lastSwapItem).hasClass('current'))
        {
            $(firstSwapItem).addClass('next');
            $(firstSwapItem).addClass('next').css('opacity',0);
        }
        else if($(firstSwapItem).hasClass('next') && $(lastSwapItem).hasClass('current'))
        {
            $(firstSwapItem).addClass('current');       
            $(wrapHelperItem).addClass('next');
            $(firstSwapItem).removeClass('next');
        }
    }

    setupUnique();
    });
    }
});
}

function makeUnique(){
$('.w-slides').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',name+num);
    num++;
    setupUnique();
    });
}

makeUnique();
```

Comment: The error I'm seeing in the javascript console is "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".  Is this the error you're referring to?

Comment: @DanEsparza Different browser, different error.. I am seeing the recursion error in FF.

Answer (score 0):

I could be reading your braces incorrectly -- but are you calling `setupUnique()` from inside **setupUnique**?

That would cause a problem.

Comment: Hi Dan. Yes, I had been trying to call from within the function. I had done this in the past without issues. Would I best off calling an external function that then calls this function again? In the case of recursion, when would it be appropriate to use this?

Comment: Sorry if that question is a bit deep for this post, I don't have a senior dev above me so it's just me, the web, and the good graces of the dev forums.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you're trying to accomplish, [creating your own jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started) is probably the best approach. However, using your general approach and what you started with, here is something that should get you going in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/UQmc3/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Wait for the document to be ready
    makeUnique();
});

function makeUnique() {
    var name = 'fader'; // scope these variables to the function
    var num = 1;
    $('.w-slides').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', name + num);
        num++;
    });
    setupUnique();
}

function setupUnique() {
    var animateSpeed = 2000; // scope these variables to the function
    var timerInterval = 4000; // this is the timer interval

    $('.w-slides').each(function(i) {
            var $this = $(this); //refers to the current .w-slides in the .each()
            var $nextItem = $this.find('li.next');
            var $currentItem = $this.find('li.current');
            var $firstSwapItem = $this.find('li:first');
            var $lastSwapItem = $this.find('li:last');
            var $wrapHelperItem = $this.find('li.current + li');
            // create new instance of SlideSwaper
            var slideSwap = new SlideSwaper($this, $nextItem, $currentItem, 
                                            $firstSwapItem, $lastSwapItem, 
                                            $wrapHelperItem);
    });

    function SlideSwaper($this, $nextItem, $currentItem, $firstSwapItem, 
                         $lastSwapItem, $wrapHelperItem) {
        this.$this = $this;
        this.$nextItem = $nextItem;
        this.$currentItem = $currentItem;
        this.$firstSwapItem = $firstSwapItem;
        this.$lastSwapItem = $lastSwapItem;
        this.$wrapHelperItem = $wrapHelperItem;

        var fadeTimer = setInterval(function() {
            // Hide/Show the appropriate <li>
            // Everything commented out below should be combined, 
            // don't hide/show your li and then check after that to 
            // see if everything is ok - do your check first, and 
            // then as you check show/hide the approriate <li>
            /*$nextItem.animate({opacity:1}, speed, 'linear', function() {
                $currentItem.removeClass('current').css('opacity',0);
                        $nextItem.addClass('current').removeClass('next');
                        $wrapHelperItem.addClass('next').css('opacity',0);'
                        console.log('checker');
                        checker();
            });

            if($lastSwapItem.hasClass('current')) {
                        $firstSwapItem.addClass('next').css('opacity',0);
            } else if($firstSwapItem.hasClass('next') && $lastSwapItem.hasClass('current')) {
                        $firstSwapItem.addClass('current').removeClass('next');     
                        $wrapHelperItem.addClass('next');
            }*/
        }, timerInterval);

    }

}
```

Basically, you need to create new instances of an object to keep references to the appropriate `<ul>` intact. Also:

- none of this should start until the document is ready
- use a variable to reference `$(this)` when referencing multiple times
- you had no timer function (I assume you want the slides to change every `x` seconds)
- variables should be scoped to their functions (in your case, all of them can and should be)
- some of your function names are ambiguous and could be improved (ex. `makeUnique` could be `initializeSwapper`, etc).

You'll have to do a little work to get the slides to change how you want. Right now, the anonymous function set to `fadeTimer` will execute every 4 seconds at which point you can change the slides as necessary.

If you're not using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), I'd suggest you [check it out](https://getfirebug.com/).